# Is there a way to lower bound the left tail probability of a random variable?

Tags: probability, distribution-tails

I am looking for a bound of the form $P(X<0) > t$ where $X$ is a general random variable with positive mean, and all of whose (or most) moments exist. $t$ is ideally a function of these moments. I am looking for a non-trivial bound of this kind.

Comment: Best I can think of is that if your first moment is negative, you can use a Chebyshev bound: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality

Answer (score 0):

If X has negative mean, we would have by Chebyshev:

P(X $\geq$ 0) $\leq$ P($|X-EX| \geq |EX|$) $\leq$ $\frac{E(X-EX)^2}{(EX)^2}$

(Thus, $P(X < 0) > 1 - \frac{E(X-EX)^2}{(EX)^2}$)

Other bounds involving higher moments should also be possible (and I would guess that whichever of your moments imposes the tightest conditions would "win"), but this is a simple and yet non-trivial bound)

Comment: I said positive mean.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that; uh you might be able to use the third moment but I can't see it directly.